# Determine the Laplace Transform of $te^{-3t}\sin(2t)$

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

As the question says, I want to find the Laplace Transform of $te^{-3t}\sin(2t)$. It seems like I can just use the formula here right? So $L=\frac{2}{(s+3)^2+4}$, using the formula and definition of a Laplace Transform.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\newcommand{\L}[1]{\mathcal{L} \left\{ #1 \right\}(s)}
\newcommand{\dv}{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}}
$
Not quite. You seem to be finding just $\L{ e^{-3t} \sin(2t) }$, which, while necessary in the derivation of the answer, will need to be differentiated and multiplied by $-1$ to get there.

---

In more detail:

Using $(30)$ from [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf) with $n=1$ and $f(t) = e^{-3t} \sin(2t)$ yields

$$\L{te^{-3t} \sin(2t)} = -\dv \L{ e^{-3t} \sin(2t) }$$

From here, then we apply identity $(21)$ from that source with $a=-3$ and $b=2$ to obtain

$$\L{ e^{-3t} \sin(2t) } = \frac{2}{(s+3)^2 + 4}$$

Then we need to take the derivative of this, and get

$$\dv \L{ e^{-3t} \sin(2t) } = \dv \frac{2}{(s+3)^2 + 4} = \frac{-4(s+3)}{((s+3)^2 + 4)^2}$$

and consequently

$$\L{te^{-3t} \sin(2t)} = \frac{ 4(s+3)}{((s+3)^2 + 4)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(t)=\sin 2t$,
the Laplace transform is
$$
f(s)
=\mathcal{L} \{ F(t) \}
=\frac{2}{s^2+4}
$$
Then use respectively the
two Laplace transform properties
$\mathcal{L} \{ e^{at} F(t) \}
=f(s-a)$ and
$\mathcal{L} \{ t F(t) \}
= - \frac{d}{ds} f(s)$.

The LT of
$G(t)=e^{-3t} F(t)$
is
$$
g(s)
=\frac{2}{(s+3)^2+4}
$$
and the required LT is
$$
h(s)
= - \frac{d}{ds} g(s)
= \frac{4(s+3)}{[(s+3)^2+4]^2}
$$